# Usage of space before punctuation mark / Leerzeichen vor Satzzeichen

Tags: punctuation

I would like to know what the rules are in German (and if they are different in Switzerland) with respect to spaces before punctuation marks.

I know for sure that `.` and `,` are never preceded by a space. But what about `:`, `;`, `?` and `!` (Doppelpunkt, Semikolon, Fragezeichen, Ausrufezeichen)?

Should I, just like in French, add some space before these punctuation marks? Or not?

Comment: Ich dachet french spacing bedeutet, einen größeren Abstand (z.B. 2 Leerzeichen) *nach* dem Satzzeichen zu lassen, nicht davor.

Comment: Der Begriff `french spacing` war mit bis heute unbekannt. Im Englischen waren 2 Leerzeichen nach Satzende en vogue um 1900. Im Französischen würde ich nie 2 Leerzeichen benutzen. Aber vor und nach `:` kommt je ein Leerzeichen. Siehe auch http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_sentence_spacing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to both my knowledge and [this page](http://faql.de/typographie.html#interpunktion), you should not.

A space before any of the punctuation marks you mention is colloquially referred to as a ["Plenk"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plenk), derived from English: "blank". Using that makes fun of the mistake of putting a space where none belongs.

Comment: Yup, it's wrong to do that in German. It's done a lot, though, mainly by computer illiterates.

Answer (score 4):

Never, never, never and never use a blank before one those  punctuation marks, except  <sub>(except)</sub>  if you're writing in the internet (web, email , you name it) and your sentence ends in a webadress like http://german.stackexchange.com .

But there are other punctuation marks, which have other rules, as Em1 points out in the comments: Parenthesis do have space on the outer side, but not on the inner side, and if nested, there is no space between them, and not to other punctation marks:

```
foo ((example) bar (baz)), foobar
```

For the dash - we have space before and behind. For the ellipse of triple dots, …, the sentence end is omitted if it is just a dot. Before the ellipse, you put a non breaking space, to avoid it being placed at the beginning of line. Else, it is threatened as what it is replacing.

Comment: If you refer to those mentioned in the question, you're right. But what about ..., –, (, usw.

Comment: @Em1: Ok, ein Satzzeichen nach ... ist einleuchtend. Aber welche Konstruktion hätte einen Binde-, Trenn- oder Gedankenstrich vor einem Satzzeichen, die eine Leerstelle erfordern würde? Wann kann man eine Klammer öffnen, und ein Satzzeichen folgen lassen. Sind Klammern überhaupt Satzzeichen? Klammern haben immer Luft nach außen ({übertrieben [sic!]} hier gezeigt) und nicht nach innen. Bei geschachtelten Klammern eintfällt der Abstand zwischen inneren und äußeren. Klammern, die zu einem Satz gehören, stehen in dem Satz, und das Satzzeichen erst dahinter (der Teil i. d. Klammer ohne eigenes).

Comment: Klar, sind Klammern Satzzeichen (oder etwa nicht). Also VOR der öffnenden Klammer ist auf jeden Fall eine Leerzeichen (ja richtig, dass ist nach außen) und - so am Rande bemerkt - beim Gedankenstrich davor und dahinter. Oder reden wir einfach nur aneinandervorbei?

Comment: Ah - ich habe jetzt gedacht es geht um Ausnahmen; dass vor einem Satzzeichen (,.:;!?) doch ein Leerraum kommt, wenn eines der genannten anderen Satzzeichen davorsteht. Die 3 Punkte haben mich darauf gebracht: Wenn auf die ein weiterer Punkt als Satzzeichen folgen soll, so ist der ja in der Ameisenstraße kaum mehr auszumachen .... - die 3 Punkte werden einfach ans letzte Wort geklebt? Das wäre... .

Comment: Ok, dann ist ja alles klar :)

Comment: Wie man mit den Auslassungspunkten umgeht, kannst du auf [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslassungspunkte) sehen, am Satzende wird [KEIN punkt](http://www.sven-jahn.de/deutsch/AmtReg/seiten/s161.html) mehr gesetzt

Comment: Jetzt hast du dir den upvote verdient ;p

Comment: ... oder doch Du mit Deinem Wikipedialink?